# Open oracle db with broken Redo-Log-Blockheader

Tags: database, oracle, corruption

We have a database for developers. A handful of records that are missing are uncritical. It should only be the database available again and that is my goal.

The state of the database is as follows:

```
SQL> select instance_name, version, status from v$instance;

INSTANCE_NAME    VERSION           STATUS
---------------- ----------------- ------------
ora12            12.2.0.1.0        MOUNTED
```

If I try to open the database, it failes as:

```
SQL> alter database open;
alter database open
*
FEHLER in Zeile 1:
ORA-00354: Fehlerhafter Redo-Log-Blockheader
ORA-00353: Logfehler bei Block 14876, Verõnderung von 14597665 Zeit 01/13/2018 17:17:33
ORA-00312: Online-Log 1, Thread 1: 'C:\ORACLE\DBADMIN\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORA12\REDO01.LOG'
```

As mentioned before: A small data loss is not relevant for this database. How can I open the database?

---

Edit because of the suggestion of kfinity:

I try the suggestions from kfinity with the following outcome.

```
C:\Windows\System32>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Do Feb 1 15:54:20 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Verbunden mit:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> select instance_name, version, status from v$instance;

INSTANCE_NAME    VERSION           STATUS
---------------- ----------------- ------------
ora12            12.2.0.1.0        MOUNTED

SQL> recover database until cancel;
ORA-00279: ???nderung 14597437, erstellt von . Erforderlich f??r Thread 1


Log angeben: {<RET>=suggested | filename | AUTO | CANCEL}
CANCEL
ORA-01547: Warnung: RECOVER erfolgreich, doch OPEN RESETLOGS w??rde folgenden
Fehler ergeben
ORA-01194: Datei 1 erfordert weiteres Recovery, um konsistent zu werden
ORA-01110: Datendatei 1: 'C:\ORACLE\DBADMIN\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORA12\SYSTEM01.DBF'


ORA-01112: Media Recovery nicht gestartet


SQL> ALTER Database open resetlogs;
ALTER Database open resetlogs
*
FEHLER in Zeile 1:
ORA-00603: ORACLE server session terminated by fatal error
ORA-01092: ORACLE instance terminated. Disconnection forced
ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [4194], [32], [21], [], [], [], [],
[], [], [], [], []
Prozess-ID: 1480
Session-ID: 250 Seriennummer: 46338
```

Am I right, that the database is damaged beyond repair?

Comment: I have restored the entire machine from backup and the database is working again. Nevertheless, I am looking forward to your answers to learn how to deal with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The fix to "ORA-00354: corrupt redo log block header" is [to clear the log file with the problem](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/onlineredo008.htm#ADMIN11327) and then immediately take a full backup, since you'll have a gap in your redo history and won't be able to recover:

```
alter database clear unarchived logfile 'C:\ORACLE\DBADMIN\VIRTUAL\ORADATA\ORA12\REDO01.LOG';
```

[As this article points out](http://www.oracledistilled.com/oracle-database/troubleshooting/ora-00354-corrupt-redo-log-block-header/), if your log files are multiplexed (which they should be - keeping multiple copies on separate disks helps avoid corruption issues like this), then you can simply replace the corrupted redo log file with a clean copy of the same file from one of the other locations.

---

Edit: if it won't let you clear a logfile because it's needed for recovery, then you need to do *incomplete media recovery*, where you basically only recover up until the corrupt redo logs (and throw the rest out). [There are detailed guides on how to do this](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Incomplete_Media_Recovery), but the basic idea is to do:

```
RECOVER DATABASE UNTIL CANCEL;
```

Which will let you apply the good redo logs to the current database state. Once you've gotten up to the corrupt one, you CANCEL and do:

```
ALTER DATABASE OPEN RESETLOGS;
```

Which discards the rest of the unapplied changes and resets the database to the last consistent state (SCN) you have.

Comment: kfinity, is it really possible to execute `alter database clear unarchived` on a **mounted** database, which is not open? As far as i remember, oracle refused to clear the logfile because it was needed for recovery.

Comment: Oh, that's a good point, it's been a while since I've had to do this. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: kfinity, thank you for your update! I kept the machine with the bug and tried your suggestion. Here are the outcome:

Comment: I added the output in my first post.